# Checking Multiple Conditons Similar to SQL IN Operator

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need to do the following,and the list may possibly grow.  Is there a more succinct way to write this?  Something like a SQL IN operator?

```
<c:if test="${status == 'A' || status == 'E'}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little hacky, but.... if you can determine a character that will never appear in your status variable (here I'm using a pipe character) you could do something like

```
<c:set var='testVal' value='|${status}|' />
<c:if test="${fn:contains('|A|E|', testVal)}">
```